# laravel 4.1 upgrade now have blank screens

Tags: laravel

I've just tried upgrading a site to 4.1 from 4.0 I think I managed to follow the instructions and upgraded the scripts etc. Successfully upgraded view composer

However my pages no longer work - they are not loading anything and simply have blank html. There are no error messages so not at all clear on what;s gong on here.

Has anyone else had this behaviour? Do I need to start stripping out packages?

Any help appreciated

Comment: There's likely to be something in the logs.

Comment: I was having the same problems, it may happen because of the file permissions. Can you try to change the chmod of the storage folder by issuing: `chmod -R 0777 app/storage` from the root directory of your laravel app? And see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Is error logging turned on if not turn it on debugging in config/app.php.

Comment: Hi. I;ll look at permissions - the error log (which I always forget) shows the following error `[2013-12-25 22:57:58] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getMethods()' in C:\wamp\www\cisite\ebdowns2014\app\storage\views\f9e7a0cf8302294e71b4dc2cbe275581:17`

Comment: solved - this was partly folder permissions and also I had not updated the session.php as required in the upgrade docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You skipped this step(you already fixed, i hope this aswer helps anybody):

> Permissions
>
> After installing Laravel, you may need to grant the web server write
>   permissions to the app/storage directories. See the Installation
>   documentation for more details on configuration.

Then, once you've created your project, put this:

`sudo chmod -R 755 app/storage` or `sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage`

Comment: Partly the solution but also I needed to make the updates to session.php